# Set session in Yii framework

Tags: session, yii

I am developing a website with Yii.

I have a button in the page. I need to set a session variable when user clicks it and get the session value when user clicks on another button.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`CWebUser`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser) state methods

```
//set session variable
Yii::app()->user->setState("state_name", "value");

//check session variables
Yii::app()->user->hasState("state_name");

//get session variable
Yii::app()->user->getState("state_name");

//delete session variable (thanks @Kailas)
Yii::app()->user->setState("state_name", null);
```

Comment: Delete the state by setting

//delete state
Yii::app()->user->setState('stat_name',null);

Answer (score 2):

you can use CWebUser's [setState](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser/#setState-detail).

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('key', 'value');
```

Comment: I can't use it in view files,can I ? I guess I have to use ajax in view file to send set session request to controller, is it true?

Comment: what is the difference between what you said and Yii::app()->session ?

Comment: you can use it in view files. Yii::app()->session is read only

Comment: thank you w43L, but I set session with Yii::app()->session('test') = 'something';

Answer (score 1):

Simple

> Yii::app()->session['var'] = $encrypted_txt;

Answer (score -1):

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
```

// get a session variable. The following usages are equivalent:

```
$language = $session->get('language');
```

// set a session variable. The following usages are equivalent:

```
$session->set('language', 'en-US');
```

// remove a session variable. The following usages are equivalent:

```
$session->remove('language');
```

// check if a session variable exists. The following usages are equivalent:

```
if ($session->has('language'))
```