# session not working correctly in yii

Tags: session, yii

I am using sessions in when 
 usercontroller 
  actionlogin

```
             $userid=User::model()->fetch($username,$password);
            //  var_dump($userid);
             Yii::app()->SESSION['srid']=$userid;
```

in user model i have

```
 public function fetch($username,$password)
{

    $sql="select id FROM user where ( username='".$username. "' AND password='".$password."')";
    $connection=Yii::app()->db;
    $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
    $resuserid=$command->queryAll();
    //var_dump($resuserid);
    $result=array();
    foreach($resuserid as $key=>$val)
    {$result[]=$val;}
    return $result;
    }
```

when i access this in some other controller

person personcontroller

i need to stored the

```
$model->personid=Yii::app()->SESSION['srid'];
```

the result of

```
var_dump($model->personid);
```

something

```
  array
0 => 
array
  'id' => string '24' (length=2)
```

**the exact id is '24' but its appearing as string '24 '**

error is

```
  personid must be a number.
```

the thing is session stores it as string but i need it as integer as personid is integer ..........

as well i want to know have we to configure session in config/main ...... do i need a db for it

Please help  i am losing my mind on this

Comment: try this code `$model->personid = (int) Yii::app()->SESSION['srid'];`

Comment: personid is always 1  for the above cde

Comment: try `intval(Yii::app()->SESSION['srid']);`

Comment: This is super vulnerable to SQL Injection. I do not recommend you to do it this way

Comment: again personid is always 1

Comment: @Pierre i know that i am just using it here . the only things for know i need is session to work for me

Comment: a) Use this instead to set sessions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197462/set-session-in-yii-framework/14197600#14197600

Comment: Hey tisha do you have multiple entries in your table with same username and password ?

Comment: @Letmesee no i dont i get the exact id but it says its string  but then my need is int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public function fetch($username,$password)
{

    $sql="select id FROM user where ( username='".$username. "' AND password='".$password."')";
    $connection=Yii::app()->db;
    $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
    // use queryColumn if you have to fetch only a single column
    $resuserid=$command->queryColumn();
    //var_dump($resuserid);
    $result=array();
    foreach($resuserid as $val)
    {
         // you can cast each value as integer like this
        $result=(int) $val;

    }
    return $result;
    }
```

Note:- **Session stores the integers as integers only**. The problem was that you were storing a it as the string.
**If your query is going to return only a single value then you should use queryScalar().**

Comment: so finally your problem is solved. haan?? And never lose your mind on anything :p

Comment: It happens sometimes :) keep coding :)

Answer (score 0):

From your code `$result` is an array not a string or int.

```
{$result[]=$val;}
```

should be

```
{$result=$val;}
```

Check out [yii-user's implementation of UserIdentity](https://code.google.com/p/yii-user/source/browse/trunk/modules/user/components/UserIdentity.php?r=101) for a better way to handle logins.