# Get user details in Yii framework

Tags: yii

I am new to Yii framework and I want to get the user details of current logged in user like userid, username & his avatar and want to add that data in the head tag. I am using basic version on Yii.

How can I get this details?

Comment: you can refer this link for set session and get session value in YII.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197462/set-session-in-yii-framework/14197600

Answer (score 0):

Yii handles user data in the session using the IdentityInterface.
Let's go step by step.

You can create a class, call it User, which implements IdentityInterface. If connected with the database you can extend it to ActiveRecord, totally up to your architecture.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    ...
}
```

Add the configuration details into the config file, main.php. I work on advance template, thus its located into fronted/config. Check it for the basic one.

```
'components' => [
    ...

    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
    ],

    ....
];
```

This tells the app to get the user session details form the common\model\User class. Its in common as I use the same class for backend and the frontend, which is not the case in the basic template.

Make user login into the app

When you get the object of the User class, with valid username and password, use the following code to login the user.

```
Yii::$app->user->login($user);
```

To get the value of the user you have following sample

**Yii::$app->user->isGuest** - This tells you whether the user is logged in or not.

**Yii::$app->user->id** - Get the id of the user

**Yii::$app->user->identity->name** - `Yii::$app->user->identity` will give you access to the entire object of the User class. If you have any other attributes, use the identity and get those. Example, you can have 'avatar', which stores the avatar url, you can get it by `Yii::$app->user->identity->avatar`.

Finally to logout

```
Yii::$app->user->logout();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `setState` method.

In your `UserIdentity.php`:

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $user=User::model()->find('LOWER(username)=?',array(strtolower($this->username)));
    if($user===null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else if(!$user->validatePassword($this->password))
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
        $this->_id=$user->id;
        $this->username=$user->username;
        $this->setState("userid",$user->user_id);// set States like this
        $this->setState("username",$user->username);
        $this->setState("avatar",$user->avatar );
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return $this->errorCode;
}
```

Now anywhere get these like:

```
$userid = Yii::app()->user->getState('userid');
```

Comment: This is wrong. You can at any time access `\Yii::$app->user->identity` to get the actual user model.

Comment: The OP says `I am using basic version on Yii.` which means he's using yii2 not 1.

Comment: @Twisted1919 can you please let me know the link which says that the basic version of yii is yii2  not yii 1

Comment: Sure, have a look here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html, search for the "basic" wording.

Comment: @Twisted1919 good enough but my bad luck i cant find basic version word may be they forget to write version with basic :)